# How to display elements with identical class with button in html/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<button class="edit">EDIT PROFILE</button>
```

```
<div class="display">
<input  type="file" name="profpic" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" 
style="max-width:480px;max-height:480px;">
</div>
```

I have few elements with class **display** and i want them to be displayed **together** with single button, but i can't find solution.

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.edit');
let prof = document.querySelectorAll('.display');
btn.onclick = function(){
  prof.classList.toggle("edited");
};
```

*ofc css class **display** is set to **none** and **edited** is set to **flex***

Comment: You can not toggle the class for the return value of querySelectorAll, you need to loop over that list and toggle the class for each node it contains.

Comment: const btn = document.querySelector('.edit');
const prof = document.querySelectorAll('.display');

btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  prof.forEach(el => {
    el.classList.toggle('edited');
  })
})